# How can I boot to terminal?

Tags: elementary-os

After installing package `touchegg` my laptop will not boot.  I want to boot to terminal and run `apt-get purge touchegg`.  How can I boot to terminal and/or otherwise run this command?

I can get as far as the login screen.  I login > desktop starts to load > Freeze.

Comment: Before log in in press Ctrl+Alt+F1

Comment: @M.Becerra - That lets me login normally.  What does that do exactly?  I removed touchegg and it still crashes so I need to uninstall something else.

Comment: Well you can use `history` to check what are the last commands you ran, maybe that gives you a hint

Comment: @M.Becerra - Thanks!!  Those 2 things fixed it.  Post an answer and I'll give you credit.  It was `sudo apt-get purge gimp inkscape`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before loging in press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to change to `tty1` and use your username and password to login. After that you can use `history` to get the last commands used, and that should give you a hint on what caused the issue, and possibly a solution.

In this particular case what did it, somehow, was : `sudo apt-get purge gimp inkscape touchegg`

Answer (score 0):

Before logging in, press `Ctrl-Alt-F1`. That will open a terminal window.
 [More info regarding the different terminal key combos](https://askubuntu.com/q/811074/640732)

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-F1` works different in Elementary than it does in Ubuntu.  It does NOT take you to a terminal screen in Elementary.  It did something though which let me login.  Running history let me find the problem.  Because M. Becerra first mentioned both of these steps I picked this answer.